What does each part in com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist mean?
This is an attempt to make the question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878482/what-do-the-parameter-values-in-applesymbolichotkeys-plist-dict-represent more concise and clear and to consolidate the answers
When I run defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist, there's output like:
        54 =         {
            enabled = 0;
            value =             {
                parameters =                 (
                    65535,
                    113,
                    8388608
                );
                type = standard;
            };
        };
        55 =         {
            enabled = 1;
            value =             {
                parameters =                 (
                    65535,
                    107,
                    8912896
                );
                type = standard;
            };
        };

What do each of those numbers mean?

        «ACTION» =         {
            enabled = «IS_ENABLED»;
            value =             {
                parameters =                 (
                    «ASCII»,
                    «KEY_CODE»,
                    «MODIFIERS»
                );
                type = standard;
            };
        };


«ACTION» can be found in https://github.com/NUIKit/CGSInternal/blob/master/CGSHotKeys.h (although that list is incomplete and may not be completely accurate) and may depend on the specific OS. The ones listed in the question both open the Displays System Settings, possibly related to display brightness, at least in macOS 14 (Sonoma).
«IS_ENABLED» is 0 if the action is disabled and 1 if enabled.
«ASCII» is the ASCII code of the key. For keys with no ASCII code (eg function keys), it will be 65535 (0xFFFF in hexadecimal).
«KEY_CODE» can be found in https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes and may depend on the specific OS.
«MODIFIERS» can be found in https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/74c4621e2492fb875f0f42778d432973 and https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/blob/master/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h and may depend on the specific OS.

